# Database and class design

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

Problem - I'm creating a group forum application for school and need to create design matching for following requirements.

- Many to many relationship between Group and Group Members.
- Group member can be either Student or Staff. (May be some other user roles as well in future).
- Already there exist Student and Staff tables in my database.

Environment - Java, Spring, Hibernate, MySQL

Approaches -

1.a) DB design

group : | id | name | is_active |

group_member : | id | group_id | user_role | student_id | staff_id | is_banned | is_default_user |

1.b) Class design (DTO classes)

Group : GroupMember groupMembers[*], etc.

GroupMember : UserRole userRole, Student student, Staff staff, etc.

2.a) DB design

group : | id | name | is_active |

group_member : | id | group_id | is_banned | is_default_user |

student_member : | id | group_member_id | student_id |

staff_member : | id | group_member_id | staff_id |

2.b) Class design

Group : GroupMember groupMembers[*], etc.

GroupMember : UserRole userRole, Member member, etc.

interface Member : getMember():Object

StudentMember extends Student implements Member : getMember():Student

StaffMember extends Staff implements Member : getMember():Staff

I prefer to 2nd approach. Seems it is more extendable. In 1st approach, always 1 column is null. It's waste.

Is there any better approaches with mentioned environment (support for hibernate : I'm new bee) for this kind of matters ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other approaches. Basically, you have a Member entity, and this entity has two subclasses: StudentMember and StaffMember. The StaffMember has an association with a Staff, and the StudentMamber has an association with a Student.

This inheritance can be mapped in three different ways.

1. everything in a single table. This would lead to your first database design: the user_role column is the discriminator column, and either student_id or staff_id is null.
2. Each concrete class has its own table. This would lead to two identical tables, except one would have a student_id column and one would have a staff_id column.
3. Each class has its own table. This would lead to 3 tables: one (member) which would contain all the common columns (id, banned, group_id, etc.), one which would contain only the StudentMember specific columns (the ID, referencing the member table, and the student ID), and one which would contain the StaffMember specific columns (the ID, referencing the member table, and the staff ID).

All the approaches have pros and cons:

- the first one leads to nullable join columns, but is very efficient (no need for joins to load all the members of a group, for example). It's also impossible for another table to have a FK to a StudentMember, but only to a Member.
- the second one leads to column duplications, and needs joins to load members (but no join to load StudentMember or StaffMember), but it has no nullable foreign keys, and it's possible to have a FK to a StaffMember or a StudentMember, but not to any Member.
- the third one is inefficient, because it needs joins for every query. But it has no column duplication, and you can have foreign keys to whatever you want.

Given that you onlyhave one column which differs between the sub-entities, I would go for the first solution, which is easier to understand, query and optimize, and leads to much simpler queries.

All these inheritance strategies are described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#inheritance-strategies).

Comment: @Nizet: First, thanks for sharing your valuable reply for my lengthy question. I have some doubts to clarify. Can you please respond ?

Comment: I could respond if you said what your doubts are.

Comment: 1. In your starting point, do you mean keep Student object as a property of StudentMember class and same way for Staff ? (Student student;)
2. If the Member table increasing rate of 5000 entries/year, do you still use 1st option ? (with nullable foreign keys)
3. Did you think of extendability ? (Option 1 need add column and add a property to class, but option 3 needs add new table and add new class with change nothing)

Comment: 1. yes. 2. This is tiny. ANy option will do fine. 3. Yes, that's true.